# Push Notification Extension not called while debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, ios-app-extension

My IOS app and the Push Notification Extension work fine on my device. However when debugging (running the Extension via Xcode), the extension is not begin called when receiving a push notification. The debugger immediately detaches and no messages are shown.

What could be the reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you are sending rich notifications you should check the deployment target to be at least iOS 10

Answer (score 0):

2 main reasons:

- Not all dependencies were loaded (not embeded into app target or smth else)
- App ext consumes too much memory (> ~15 MB for Notification Service
  Extension), including app and library memory itself (!).